# R plotting integral

Tags: r, plot, integral, numerical-integration

I'm having some problems with integration function in R. I'm trying to plot the integral vo but it seems I'm not doing correctly.

```
t <- seq(0, 0.04, 0.0001)
vi <- function(x) {5 * sin(2 * pi * 50 * x)}
vo <- function(x) {integrate(vi, lower=0, upper=x)$value}

test_vect = Vectorize(vo, vectorize.args='x')
plot(t, vo(t))  # should be a cosine wave
plot(t, vi(t))  # sine wave
```

`vo` should be a sine wave but using `test_vect` gives me wrong plot and using `vo` directly gives error ***'x' and 'y' lengths differ***. Can anyone, please, help me on this matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already there. Just use `plot(t, test_vect(t))`. You can't use `vo`, as `integrate` is not a vectorized function. There is no problem to evaluate a single point like `vo(0.002)`, but you can not feed it a vector by `vo(t)`. This is why we want `Vectorize(vo)(t)`.

[image]

You said that `test_vect` is not giving the right plot. Sure? We can analytically compute the integral:

```
v <- function (x) (1-cos(100*pi*x)) / (20*pi)
```

Then let's compare:

```
sum(abs(v(t) - test_vect(t)))
# [1] 2.136499e-15
```

They are the same!

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you very much for the answer.