# Compute expectation of a 1D truncated distribution (say log-normal) in R

Tags: r

In R, I need to calculate the conditional expectation *f(z)=E[x|x < z]*, where *x* is distributed according to a parametric distribution (namely, a log-normal).

To calculate e.g. *f(2)* I've done the following:

```
zz <- rlnorm(1000,meanlog=.7,sdlog=.5)
mean(zz[zz<2])
```

However, I wonder whether there's a more direct way, not requiring to generate samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at [truncated distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution). Integrate `x * f(x)` on `(-Inf, z)`, then divide this integral by `F(z)`. [*`f(x)` is unconditional PDF; `F(x)` is unconditional CDF.*]

```
## integrand
f <- function(x, mu, sigma) x * dlnorm(x, mu, sigma)

## conditional expectation
g <- function(z, mu, sigma) {
  int <- integrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = z, mu = mu, sigma = sigma)
  int$value / plnorm(z, mu, sigma)
  }

## theoretical value
g(2, 0.7, 0.5)
# [1] 1.401472

## sample estimate
set.seed(0)
zz <- rlnorm(1000,meanlog=.7,sdlog=.5)
mean(zz[zz<2]) 
# [1] 1.40316
```

I had planed to write one or two lines of LaTeX to show why we want an integral as above, but it looks like that the Wikipedia link is informative enough.

---

> For some reason, I am not able to plot the resulting function `g`. `plot(1, g(1:10,0.7,0.5))` is giving an error.

To plot `g` you need to make it a vectorized function first. There has been some posts about plotting integral, like [R plotting integral](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39516198/4891738). Here is what we can do:

```
vg <- Vectorize(g, vectorize.args = "z")
plot(1:10, vg(1:10, 0.7, 0.5), type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. Hover, for some reason, I am not able to plot the resulting function g. If I do `z=1:10` and then `plot(z,g(z,2,3))` the resulting plot is not correct. Indeed, if I redefine `g` so that it is not divided by `plnorm(...)` I get the following error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Zheyuan's answer, did a little bit of research on conditional expectation of a function where the conditional pdf is a truncated pdf.

According to me, `mean(zz[zz < a])` is **not** the *conditional expectation* in the conditional universe *X < a*, since the pdf that was used to generate the zz values was the *original lognormal pdf* and not the *conditional truncated pdf*.

In order to compute the *conditional expectation* we must use the *truncated pdf* and draw the samples from the *truncated distribution* and the not the original lognormal distribution and then compute the expectation.

As can be seen, the values of `mean(zz[zz < a])` is always different from the conditional expectation computed using expectation with conditional (truncated) pdf, the difference increases as ***a*** increases (any intuition why?).

```
# compute the truncated pdf with x < a
tr.pdf <- function(x, a, m, s) (x < a) * (dlnorm(x, m, s) / plnorm(a, m, s))

expect.f <- function(x, a, m, s) x * tr.pdf(x, a, m, s)

cond.expect.f <- function(a, m, s) {
  return(integrate(expect.f, lower = -Inf, upper = a, a = a, m = m, s = s)$value)
}

m <- .7
s <- .5
curve(tr.pdf(x, a=2, m, s), 0, 5, col='red', ylab='y')
curve(tr.pdf(x, a=2.5, m, s), 0, 5, col='green', add=TRUE)
curve(tr.pdf(x, a=3, m, s), 0, 5, col='blue', add=TRUE)
curve(dlnorm(x, m, s), 0, 5, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
n <- 100000
zz <- rlnorm(n,meanlog=m,sdlog=s)

a <- 2
mean(zz[zz<a]) 
#[1] 1.404279
cond.expect.f(a, m, s)
#[1] 1.401472

a <- 2.5
mean(zz[zz<a]) 
#[1] 1.622174
cond.expect.f(a, m, s)
#[1] 1.617784

a <- 3
mean(zz[zz<a]) 
#[1] 1.794217
cond.expect.f(a, m, s)
#[1] 1.787772
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It seems to me the density functions you've plotted are all the same in the relevant interval (except for the fact that they are normalized so that the area under them is one). The differences you see in the values are just the difference between the "exact" value and a sample value (if you generate a new sample you can see that the sample mean can be higher or lower than the calculated value)

Comment: @Massimo: I have used quite a high value for n, that's why the fluctuations in the values of the mean will be less. But my point is different: when you compute mean(zz[zz<a]) it's not computing the conditional expectation, since you are not using the conditional truncated pdf (you are just using the original lognormal pdf). In order to compute the true conditional expectation we must use the truncated / conditional pdf, and the difference is due to that only, does that make sense?

Comment: As I wrote, in the relevant interval (z<a) the truncated distribution differ from the original distribution only for a scaling factor. Therefore, I expect the relative frequency of each value is the same in both cases. I don't expect the mean is different. The fact that in the sample mean the value is sometimes higher sometimes lower than the `cond.expect` doesn't convince you?

Comment: ok, i got you, they are different only by a scaling factor when (X < a). But when we have drawn samples from the lognormal distribution, there were some non-zero probabilities for the values X >= a to be drawn (for which we have zero-probabilities in the truncated distributions), as a result the probabilities to draw a sample with X < a got lower (by some factor, not uniform), I was just not convinced that they can't be exactly the same, although can be approximated, but the degree of error will change will different values of a. Otherwise it's fine.